# Golang struct issues to point parent struct method

Tags: pointers, go, struct, return-value, embedding

I have encountered a problem in Golang as bellow:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    name string
}
type Bar struct{
    Foo
    id string
}

func (f *Foo) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}    
func (f *Foo) Name() string {
    return f.name
}
func main(){
    f := &Foo{}
    f.SetName("Set Foo name")
    fmt.Println("Get from Foo struct name: ", f.Name() )    
    bar := &Bar{
    Foo:Foo{name: "Set Foo name from Bar struct!"},
    id: "12345678",    
    }
    fmt.Println("Bar setName(): ", bar.SetName("New value set to Foo struct name") )
    fmt.Println("Bar getName(): ", bar.Name())
}
```

Results:

> ./struct-2.go:33: bar.Foo.SetName("New value set to Foo struct name") used as value

But if I comment out this line then I can get the `bar.Name()` method works.

```
// fmt.Println("Bar setName(): ", bar.SetName("New value set to Foo struct name") )
```

Why I got that error for `bar.SetName()` method? Thanks.

Comment: `SetName` does not return anything, and you're trying to pass this "nothing" to `fmt.Println`. Which is impossible.

Comment: Oh ok sorry. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Answering the question so it won't show up anymore in the "Unanswered questions list".</sub>

---

You may pass *values* to other functions as input parameters. `fmt.Println()` has a *variadic* parameter of type `interface{}`. This means it accepts values of any type, and in any number (no limit on the number of passed arguments).

`(f *Foo) SetName()` has no return value. If you call this method either on a `*Foo` or `*Bar`, it will not produce any return values so you can't pass its "return value" to `Println()`.

`fmt.Println(bar.Name())` is OK because `Name()` returns a value of type `string`.